# What discrete vector timeseries modeling (e.g. autoregression) methods support "continuity" requirements?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autoregressive, vector-autoregression

This question is motivated by the need to do vector-valued discrete time series forecasting with some guarantees of "continuity" (or rather, a discretized analog of continuity expressed in terms of uniform bounds on the magnitude of coordinate-wise first derivatives).

In what follows, let $h,f,k$ be integers, where $h\geqslant 0$, and $f,k\geqslant 1$.

Consider a $k$-dimensional vector time series $v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_t, \ldots$ where the element $v_t \in {\mathbb R}^{k}$ at time $t$ is expressed as
$$
v_t = (x_t^1, x_t^2, \ldots, x_t^{k-1}, x_t^k).
$$

Fix integer $T\gg 0$. We seek a flexible family of mathematical forecasting models that can be fitted to the sequence $v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_T$, such that the fitted model ${\cal M}$ generates forecasts $f$ time steps into the future. ${\cal M}$  is to satisfy the two conditions given below, of which the first is "standard".

1. The model ${\cal M}$ can be applied at any time $t\in \{h, h+1, \ldots, T-1,T\}$ and computes its forecast $\tilde{v}_{t+f}$ as a function of the $h+1$ most recent series elements upto and including time step $t$, i.e.
   $$
   \tilde{v}_{t+f} \stackrel{def}{=} {\cal M}(t) \stackrel{def}{=} {\cal M}(v_t, v_{t-1}, v_{t-2}, \ldots, v_{t-h}).
   $$
   Here the forecasted vector is of the form
   $$
   \tilde v_{t+f} = (\tilde x_{t+f}^1, \tilde x_{t+f}^2, \ldots, \tilde x_{t+f}^{k-1}, \tilde x_{t+f}^k) 
   $$
   The fitted model can thus be seen as a function ${\cal M}: {\mathbb R}^{(h+1)k} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^{k}$.
2. Choose $L\in {\mathbb R}^{+}$ such that the coordinates of the vector series upto time $T$ satisfy Lipschitz conditions
   $$
   |x_t^j - x_{t-1}^j| \leqslant L
   $$
   for $0 \lt t \leqslant T$ and $1 \leqslant j \leqslant k$. Then if we apply our model ${\cal M}$ at the $f$ times points $t = T\!\!-\!\!f\!\!+\!\!1,\; T\!\!-\!\!f\!\!+\!\!2,\; \ldots,\; T\!\!-\!\!1,\; T,$ the model will generate $f$ corresponding forecasts, $\tilde{v}_{T+1}, \tilde{v}_{T+2}, \ldots \tilde{v}_{T+f}$. Prepending these $f$ forecasts with the most recent observed value $v_{T}$, we obtain the length $f+1$ sequence of $(k+1)$-dimensional vectors
   $$
   v_T, \tilde{v}_{T+1}, \tilde{v}_{T+2}, \ldots \tilde{v}_{T+f}.  
   $$
   The modeling technique should **guarantee** that this sequence of $f+1$ vectors also satisfies the same Lipshitz conditions, for the same value of $L$. *(Or, if this statement (2) is too severe a requirement, I will settle for any justifiable definition of "continuity")*

Condition (1) is easy to achieve via, e.g. lagged vector autoregression. Can such modeling techniques be extended (or are there other techniques) by which one can ensure that the flexible model ${\cal M}$ also satisfies requirement (2)?

*If a reader feels they follow the requirement definition, but knows that the standard techniques (e.g. VARMAX or other variants of VAR) cannot be made to achieve condition (2), I would greatly appreciate a comment to this effect.*